# Electron app mac app store requirements (sandboxing?)

Tags: electron, electron-builder, mac-app-store, code-signing-certificate, appstore-sandbox

Is it an absolute requirement to make your app sandboxed? Can you upload apps to App Store without this entitlement?

My app works perfectly without the "com.apple.security.app-sandbox" entitlement, but adding it breaks everything. The app crashes immediately and I'm getting the "EXC_BAD_ACCESS (Code Signature Invalid)" error.

If it's a must, is there a good tutorial about how to make "sandbox" work with electron? I tried to Google it, but there seem to be many different guides and recommendations. I'm not sure which one to follow.

I'm using electron builder 21.2.0 (which has electron-osx-sign) with Electron 6.1.9.

My understanding is that in order to build a proper MAS package, I need to do the following:

- sign the app using "Mac App Distribution" and "Mac App Installer"
  certificates
- sign all native dependencies as well with the same certificates
- Request the following entitlements (besides the ones my app actually needs)

  `<key>com.apple.security.application-groups</key>
  <array>
  <string>TEAM_ID.your.bundle.id</string>
  </array>
  <key>com.apple.security.cs.allow-unsigned-executable-memory</key>
  <true/>
  <key>com.apple.security.cs.allow-jit</key>
  <true/>
  <key>com.apple.security.cs.disable-library-validation</key>
  <true/>`

My app requires only these entitlements:

```
 <key>com.apple.security.network.client</key>
 <true/>
 <key>com.apple.security.network.server</key>
 <true/>
 <key>com.apple.security.files.user-selected.read-only</key>
 <true/>
 <key>com.apple.security.files.user-selected.read-write</key>
 <true/>
```

Is there anything else I'm missing?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Yes it's an absolute requirement to make your app sandboxed for Mac App Store.

Comment: Im getting this exact error, @mahaltertin did you find a solution?